# String replacements in files while performing a MAKE

Tags: replace, makefile

I have a existing project I am working on, currently there is a line in the make file

```
VERSION := $(shell ${GIT} describe --tags --always)
```

It ends up storing a string similar to `v2.3-9-gcdf3820` in to the `VERSION` variable. That variable is eventually used to name the file during a package process.

What I would like to do is have make write out a `Example.version` file which would have the following format.

```
{
    "NAME":"Examle",
    "VERSION":
    {
        "MAJOR":2,
        "MINOR":3,
        "PATCH":0,
        "BUILD":0
    }
}
```

So it takes in the version numbers up to the first `-` then fills the rest with 0's. The result from `describe` could have 1 to 4 version numbers in it so I wanted to be flexible.

The problem is I am now stuck on how I should proceed next. I made a `Example.version.template` file

```
{
    "NAME":"Examle",
    "VERSION":
    {
        "MAJOR":{MAJOR},
        "MINOR":{MINOR},
        "PATCH":{PATCH},
        "BUILD":{BUILD}
    }
}
```

I know how to read in the file and write out the file from inside the makefile, and I know how to replace the text once I have each of my variables. What I don't know how to do is how to I turn `v2.3-9-gcdf3820` in to the equivalent of

```
MAJOR := 2
MINOR := 3
PATCH := 0
BUILD := 0
```

How do I split my string up and strip of that leading `v` from within `make`?

Comment: This kind of string manipulation is not really possible using make alone.  I recommend you write a little shell script that will generate the file given the version string as input, then write a make rule that invokes the shell script.

Answer (score 2):

While I completely agree with @MadScientist that make isn't the most suited to this task and that a small shell script is likely a better option it is possible (given assumptions about input values) to do this manipulation using make itself.

```
$ cat desc.mk
define p
$(info $1:$($(1)):)
endef
raw := v2.3-9-gcdf3820
$(call p,raw)
split := $(subst -, ,$(raw))
$(call p,split)
ver := $(subst v,,$(word 1,$(split)))
$(call p,ver)
versplit := $(subst ., ,$(ver))
$(call p,versplit)
MAJOR := $(or $(word 1,$(versplit)),0)
$(call p,MAJOR)
MINOR := $(or $(word 2,$(versplit)),0)
$(call p,MINOR)
PATCH := $(or $(word 3,$(versplit)),0)
$(call p,PATCH)
BUILD := $(or $(word 4,$(versplit)),0)
$(call p,BUILD)

all: ;
$ make -qf desc.mk
raw:v2.3-9-gcdf3820:
split:v2.3 9 gcdf3820:
ver:2.3:
versplit:2 3:
MAJOR:2:
MINOR:3:
PATCH:0:
BUILD:0:
```

It might also make sense to use `git describe --tags --always --abbrev=0` to have git drop the `-9-gcdf3820` (or whatever) for you from the start (at least for this usage) since that eliminates a good amount of the work needed.

Edit: A little cleverness from @laune gets a cleaned up last few lines:

```
versplit := $(subst ., ,$(ver)) 0 0 0 0
MAJOR := $(word 1,$(versplit))
$(call p,MAJOR)
MINOR := $(word 2,$(versplit))
$(call p,MINOR)
PATCH := $(word 3,$(versplit))
$(call p,PATCH)
BUILD := $(word 4,$(versplit))
$(call p,BUILD)
```

Comment: Great! - A little less noise is possible by using `versplit := $(subst ., ,$(ver)) 0 0 0 0` and omitting the `$(or)`: `MAJOR := $(word 1,$(versplit))` etc.